# Change bash programmable completion (tab completion) output format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tab-completion, programmable-completion

Bash tab completion conveniently executes some `ls`-like function whenever there are multiple completion options.  For example, if `ls` yields

```
test1      test2      test3    randomfile
```

and all of those entries are folders then `cd tes<tab><tab>` yields

```
test1/ test2/ test3/
```

I have my `ls` command aliased to nicely display colors, formatting, etc., but tab completion just spits out the plain, unformatted completion options.  Is there a way to format the programmable / tab completion output just like `ls`?

Details:
Bash 3.2.5

Some promising sites that I may not have been knowledgeable enough to utilize:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bash#Tab_completion
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html

Comment: The articles may be of help: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316 http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2.